# Issue testing JsonProcessingException without mock

Tags: java, jackson

- What I am trying to achieve:

I want to write a unit test case, hopefully without mocking, which can help test a JsonProcessingException.

I have this piece of code I would like to test:

```
    public MyPojo question(String jsonString) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyPojo.class);
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unrecognized property from {}", jsonString);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Input malformed");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("How to get here? ={}", jsonString);
            throw new CustomRuntimeExeption(e);
        }
    }
```

This piece of code is from a third-party code library, I cannot change this piece of code.

- What did I try

I want to reach the third branch, the JsonProcessingException.
Therefore, I created a test where the input looks like `{"unknown_property": "value"}`
However, this would go to UnrecognizedPropertyException.

Then, I created a test where the input is `{"unknown_property": "val`
However, this would go to JsonParseException.

- Question:

What kind of input can I give to this method, which will make it go into the third branch JsonProcessingException?

#Edit
To make the question more specific: Here is a list of exceptions that extend class `JsonProcessingException` as of jackson version `2.15.2`:

```
JsonProcessingException
├── StreamWriteException
│   └── JsonGenerationException -
├── StreamReadException
│   ├── JsonParseException +
│   │   └── (...)
│   ├── InputCoercionException -
├── DatabindException
│   └── JsonMappingException +
│       └── (...)
└── StreamConstraintsException -
```

Legend:

```
+: exceptions that I can trigger
-: exceptions that Im unable to trigger
```

So, based on above list, I need to trigger one of the following exceptions: `JsonGenerationException`, `InputCoercionException`, `StreamConstraintsException`.

Comment: I'm afraid that would be a very niche exception. I'm not sure that it is even possible to archieve that without somehow corrupting the jackson dependencies.
All the UnrecognizedPropertyException, JsonParseException and JsonMappingException inherit from JsonProcessingException.
The only possible exceptions you have left are: JsonGenerationException, InputCoercionException and StreamConstraintsException.
Personally, I don't know a way to invoke them using the modern version of Jackson and the readValue method that returns a regular POJO.

Comment: You are correct, this is why I started the question. Was hoping to bump into someone who knows